# OpenGL Duplicating Vertex Arrays

Tags: c++, opengl

I am looking for some clarification and some guidance regarding duplicating indices that are already in an array.I need to from what I gather duplicate indices so that I can render a cube (each side a different colour).
My cube is read in from a "OBJ" file.

Current Code

```
using std::vector;

vector<GLfloat>vertex;
vector<GLuint>faces;

GLubyte color1[] =
{
   255,255,0,
   255,255,0,
   255,255,0,
   255,255,0,

   255,0,255,
   255,0,255,
   255,0,255,
   255,0,255

};

struct OBJVertex
{
   GLint f1;
   GLint f2;
   GLint f3;

   GLfloat x;
   GLfloat y;
   GLfloat z;

}obj;

int OBJLoader::LoadOBJData(string filename)
{
   ifstream f_obj;

   string line;

   f_obj.open(filename, ios::in);

while (!f_obj.eof())
{
    getline(f_obj, line);

    if (line.find("v") != line.npos)
    {
        sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "v %f %f %f ", &obj.x, &obj.y, &obj.z);
        vertex.push_back(obj.x);
        vertex.push_back(obj.y);
        vertex.push_back(obj.z);
    }
    if (line.find("f ")!= line.npos)
    {
        sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "f %d %d %d ", &obj.f1, &obj.f2, &obj.f3);
        obj.f1 = obj.f1 - 1;
        obj.f2 = obj.f2 - 1;
        obj.f3 = obj.f3 - 1;

        faces.push_back(obj.f1);
        faces.push_back(obj.f2);
        faces.push_back(obj.f3);
    }
}
return 0;
}
void OBJLoader::RenderOBJ()
{
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
   glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

   glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color1);
   glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertex[0]);

   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,faces.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&faces[0]);

   glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

Am I correct in thinking I need to bind both the vertex and colour array using glBindBuffer?

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertex[0]);
```

I currently have a colour array setup named "color1",this colours the top and bottom faces of the cube after binding the first vertex and colour array am I correct in thinking I can create two more colour arrays for the remaining sides of the cube?

Idea?

```
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color1);    // first colour array //
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertex[0]);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, faces.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&faces[0]);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertex[0]); 



glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color2);    // second colour array //
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertex[0]);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, faces.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&faces[0]);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertex[0]);
```

----Update----

Sorry, but I made a colour array per face  but it is just overwriting the previous array.Can someone explain what I have not done right?

```
GLubyte color1[] =
{
    255,255,0,
    255,255,0,
    255,255,0,
    255,255,0,

    255,0,255,
    255,0,255,
    255,0,255,
    255,0,255

    };

GLubyte color2[] =
{
    255,0,0,
    255,0,0,
    255,0,0,
    255,0,0,

    0,0,255,
    0,0,255,
    0,0,255,
    0,0,255
};

GLubyte color3[] =
{
    0,255,255,
    0,255,255,
    0,255,255,
    0,255,255,

    255,0,255,
    255,0,255,
    255,0,255,
    255,0,255
};

GLubyte color4[] =
{
    255,255,255,
    255,255,255,
    255,255,255,
    255,255,255,

    0,255,0,
    0,255,0,
    0,255,0,
    0,255,0
};

void OBJLoader::RenderOBJ()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertex[0]);

    glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color1);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color2);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color3);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color4);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, faces.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &faces[0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, faces.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &faces[0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, faces.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &faces[0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, faces.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &faces[0]);

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

----OBJ----

```
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
f 5 1 4
f 5 4 8
f 3 7 8
f 3 8 4
f 2 6 3
f 6 7 3
f 1 5 2
f 5 6 2
f 5 8 6
f 8 7 6
f 1 2 3
f 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you don't need to bind a buffer at all since you send the index of your buffer directly into `glColorPointer()`.

Think of it as sending a pointer to your buffer directly to OpenGL to read from. You can create more color buffers and simply change your `glColorPointer()`.

```
glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color2);
//...
glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, color3);
```

alternatively you can have all colors in one buffer called color and simply pass the right offset. assuming you had 72 components for three colors in a single buffer you can do.

```
glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &color[0]);
//...
glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &color[24]);
//...
glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &color[48]);
```

You only need to bind buffers if you pass a null pointer like this

```
//setup your array buffer
GLuint colorBuffID;
glGenBuffers(1, &colorBuffID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(unsigned char), color1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
//...
//use your array buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffID);
glColorPointer( 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, (const void*)( 0 ) );
// draw the quad
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

> If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
>   target (see glBindBuffer) while a color array is specified, pointer is
>   treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. Also,
>   the buffer object binding (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING) is saved as color
>   vertex array client-side state (GL_COLOR_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING).

Refer https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColorPointer.xml

Comment: I attempted to impairment a colour array per face but it is overwriting the previous array,what have I done wrong (see updated section)?

Comment: You need to set the color pointer then draw, then set next one then draw. The color pointer will always have your latest array according to your code. Follow set array 1 then draw, then set array 2 and draw and so on.

Comment: @Alasdairaryan Also arrent you drawing the same face each time? `&faces[0]`

Comment: Well yes, I am should they be divided to match the colour array?

Comment: Your code is actually drawing the cube 4 times but applies the color to first face only in your faces array. Since all your faces are in a single array, put all your colors in a single array too matching the size and draw once.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me,I set up my colour pointer using "faces[0]",it now renders more colours but in a weird order.I also see to have a flickering vertex.                                                      http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x248/Terexdemag/Untitled_zpsaa6hjxcp.png

Comment: I just solved the flickering by using triangles instead of triangle strip.I also forgot to say that I set up a colour array of 36 which is the same as the faces.